# Which one is which ? (True Positive, True Negative, False Positive, False Negative)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

I am running confusion matrix on my own custom model using Tensorflow Object Detection API. I am using Faster R-CNN Inception v2 pets. I get this output:

```
Processed 100 images
Processed 200 images
Processed 300 images
Processed 400 images
Processed 500 images
Processed 500 images

Confusion Matrix:
[[1281.  233.]
 [ 581.    0.]]

  category  precision_@0.5IOU  recall_@0.5IOU
0   person            0.68797        0.846103
```

From this matrix:

```
[[1281.  233.]
 [ 581.    0.]]
```

Which one is true positive, true negative, false positive, false negative ?

I am using code from this [github](https://github.com/svpino/tf_object_detection_cm). It said that this [link](https://www.shiftedup.com/2018/10/10/confusion-matrix-in-object-detection-api-with-tensorflow) would provide more explanation about this code, but the post went missing. So, i am confused.

Also, can i calculate accuracy from this results ? Sorry if i'm wrong.

Comment: You can find this information in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix There is no need to ask a question here about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below image.

[image]

More information about confusion matrix can be found here.
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/04/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/

Answer (score 0):

True positive : 1281
True negative : 0.
False Negative: 581.
False Positive: 233.

Confussion matrix is a performance measurement for machine learning classification problem where output can be two or more classes or simplify we can assume CM calculate accuracy/loss your model.